# Windows SCM reports that mongodb has started, yet initial connections to mongodb fail

Tags: windows, mongodb, version-control, dependencies

We are running mongodb (v2.0.6) as a service on Windows.  We have created several other services that are dependent on mongodb, and have created the appropriate dependency on mongodb for those services.  As the collections in our mongodb have grown, we are starting to see failures in our services while trying to connect to mongodb on startup.  It appears that mongodb is reporting to the windows SCM that it has started, yet it doesn't appear to be ready to accept client connections at that point.  Has anybody else seen this condition?  We currently have several hacks in place to get around this, but I'm trying to find out if this is a bug in mongodb, i.e., is it still asynchronously initializing when it tells the SCM that it has started?

Comment: What do the mongodb logs say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mongod.exe registers immediately with the SCM when started as a service, but may take some time to preallocate files, especially the oplog in the local database if it is large.  It does the same thing when run inside a console window.  Negotiating when joining a replica set can also take some time.  It is ready for connections once it logs "waiting for connections on ..." to the log file.

If you think it should behave differently, by, for example, remaining in SERVICE_START_PENDING state with the SCM until it is ready to accept connections, please file a Jira ticket with the details of your proposal.  We're not married to the current behavior, but it does match the behavior it shows in console windows and on other operating systems.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I will file a ticket because the current way that it works doesn't reliably allow mongodb to be a dependency of another service (which is how we are using it).  I would expect to be able to connect to the server when it claims that it has started.  If not I would need to attempt my initial connection inside a loop, but that would also need a time limit in the case where mongodb isn't going to accept connections...

Comment: Tad, Should the jira ticket be filed in the 'Core Server' project?

Comment: The following ticket has been filed.  https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7306